# Internet Explorer 11 can’t access HTTPS on non standard port (8443)?

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer, https

I have a road warrior who is accessing one of our servers from its IP address.

For a few days he cannot access to a service which listen on 8443 https TCP port. HTTP version works well on port 8080.

The URL is valid and work well with other browsers like chrome, but IE and Edge fails with DNS Error. I cannot understand why DNS is used in this situation.

URL is like:

```
https://192.168.0.2:8443/foo/bar
```

I’ve tested a lot of things, ran anti-malware, disabled IE functionality and re-enabled, disabled antivirus, reset all parameters… without any success.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: What's the _specific error message?_

Comment: ~"Internet Explorer cannot access to this web page" from debug console i see "dnserror"

Comment: Possible reason is likely IE settings (invalid/untrusted certificate, unsupported TLS version, custom network settings).

Comment: "dnserror.htm" is a generic error page. IIRC somewhere at the bottom, it gives a more technical formulation.

Comment: Internet Explorer should never be utilized and if required, use a Chromium browser's [IETab](https://www.ietab.net/) emulator [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en-US)

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is IE's security or network settings:

- Invalid/untrusted certificate

  - (in this case, however, a custom error message is printed AFAIK)
- Unsupported TLS version (no intersection in supported versions between browser and server)
- explicit custom network settings present (proxy or dial-up connection)

I consider the 2nd one the most probable. Support for older TLS versions is gradually phased out by browser vendors as vulnerabilities in them are discovered and fixed and vast majority of servers are updated. While at your private server, you are likely not updating and reconfiguring server software as you should. So, there may have been an update to IE that phased out support for even the newest version that your server is configured to use.

If you can use a sniffer, looking at the packets may give more info on the source of the error.

There's also [*"Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" error"* KB article by M$](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/956196) that shows several troubleshooting steps, including checking the aforementioned network settings.

Comment: It's not the untrusted certificate alert... nor an unsupported version as i have activated all of them for testing purpose. Proxy settings are OK, On this same machine it doesn't work through both VPN and LAN. I'll try the sniffer option next time he'll come in the office.